# How to count relationships (of one type) to a node using py2neo

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

Using py2neo 4.x, neo4j 3.5.3, python 3.7.x

What I have: a node from the graph `a`

```
graph = Graph(
    host="alpha.graph.domain.co",
    auth=('neo4j', 'theActualPassword')
)
# grab the graph
a = Node("Type", url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivendi")
# create a local node with attributes I should be able to MERGE on
graph.merge(a,"Type","url")
# do said merge
graph.pull(a)
# pull any attributes (in my case Labels) that exist on the node in neo4j...
# ...but not on my local node
# better ways to do this also would be nice in the comments
relMatch = RelationshipMatcher(graph)
```

What I want: the count of how many `"CREATED"` relationships are connected to `a`[image: A neo4j return describing how these relationships are connected to node a] (in this case, 7)

What I've tried:

`x = relMatch.get(20943820943)` using one of the IDs of the relationships to see what's what. It returns `None`, which the [docs](https://py2neo.org/v4/matching.html#py2neo.matching.RelationshipMatcher) say means

> If no such Relationship is found, py:const:None is returned instead. Contrast with matcher[1234] which raises a KeyError if no entity is found.

which leaves me thinking I'm coming at it all wrong.

also: `relMatch.match(a,"CREATED")` 
which raises

> raise ValueError("Nodes must be supplied as a Sequence or a Set")

telling me that I'm definitely not reading the docs right.

Not necessarily using this class, which probably isn't what I think it is, how do I get a count of how many `["CREATED"]` are pointed at `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `RelationshipMatcher`, you can simply take a count using `len`. So if I read your code correctly, you'll need something like:

```
count = len(RelationshipMatcher(graph).match((None, a), "CREATED"))
```

Or even easier:

```
count = len(graph.match((None, a), "CREATED"))
```

(since `graph.match` is a shortcut to `RelationshipMatcher(graph)`)

The `(None, a)` tuple specifies an ordered pair of nodes (relationships in one direction only) where the start node is any node and the end node is `a`. Using `len` simply evaluates the match and returns a count.

Comment: Nigel, you the real MVP

Answer (score 1):

Below works, and is easier to write than the previous implementation, but I don't think it's the right way to do it.

```
result = graph.run(
    "MATCH(a) < -[r:CREATED]-(b) WHERE ID(a)=" + str(a.identity) + " RETURN count(r)"
).evaluate()
print(result)
```